# Different errors while connecting to the internet - TLS handshake, PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR, SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG

Tags: networking, virtualbox, firefox, internet

Im running Ubuntu 20.04 on Windows10 with a DELL laptop using VMware.
While trying to access any website using the built in firefox browser i get errors like - PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR, SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG.
I also get a similar error while trying to connect to a google account from Ubuntu - The precise error was: Error performing TLS handshake: An unexpected TLS packet was received.

I tried running Ubuntu with VirtualBox too but I also couldnt access the internet.
Tried googling the issue and used `about:config` to tweak different settings in the browser but that also didnt help. Honestly, I dont think its a browser issue since I installed GNOME browser and I get "The precise error was: Error performing TLS handshake: An unexpected TLS packet was received."

Any help would be greatly appreciated